# Erro ao digitar GIT PUSH

Tags: git, github

Estou na minha máquina e quero fazer upload dos arquivos na minha máquina local para o meu repositorio no *[github.com](https://github.com/)*.

Já executei os comandos `git add`, `git commit` e só falta subí-los. Quando executo `git remote -v`, retorna o seguinte:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:romulosousa27/php.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:romulosousa27/php.git (push)
otigin  git.github.com:romulosousa27/php.git (fetch)
otigin  git.github.com:romulosousa27/php.git (push)
teste   https://github.com/romulosousa27 (fetch)
teste   https://github.com/romulosousa27 (push)
```

Nesse ponto, ele já esta preparado para o `push`?
Se sim , quando eu executo o comando `git push`, é retornado isso:

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

**P.S:** Minha Chave `SSH` já esta configurada.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O git já está te dando a solução. Utiliza o comando:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Onde o origin é o nome que você colocou quando usou o comando `git remote add`, e `master` é o nome da branch que você vai fazer o push. Usando esse comando você só vai precisar fazer essa associação da branch uma vez, nos próximos pushs o git não vai mais pedir a associação e você poderá rodar apenas o `git push` sem informar o nome da branch.

Comment: $ git push --set-upstream origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Esse repositório github.com/romulosousa27/php.git não existe de fato. Verifiquei no github e não achei. Você deixou ele privado? Se sim, verifica as permissões no projeto para clonar/fazer push.

Comment: Na verdade ele não existe, imaginei que quando eu fizesse um push ele criaria um repositorio default... Usei a interface do github e pensei que fosse o mesmo principio.Então devo criar um repositorio, clonar e comita-lo?

Comment: Isso, precisa criar o projeto no github e aí você associa o teu diretório local do projeto ao projeto remoto usando o git remote add. Logo que você cria ele mostra uma página com os comandos necessários para associar um projeto local existente ao remoto.

Comment: Pow guiliana deu certo aqui, era só criar o repositorio mesmo. Valeu mesmo, você fez uma criança feliz hoje hehe

Answer (score 15):

Não é suficiente escrever somente `git push`, é necessário escrever qual `remote` e o `branch` o qual será atualizado.
Exemplo:

```
git push teste branchDeTrabalho
```

Comment: Esse branch seria o origin master ou o caminho ate o repositorio?

Comment: o caminho já está gravado no `remote` (origin), o branch é o master, ou qualquer outro branch que você tenha dado checkout

Answer (score 2):

Existe um atalho que pode ser usado:

```
git push -u origin master
```

O parâmetro `-u` significa que sua branch local será configurada para rastrear a nova branch `master` criada no repositório `origin`. Se a branch master não existe no repositório remoto, ela será criada, caso contrário ela será atualizada.

Answer (score 1):

Passo a passo para dar push em um repositório remoto sem maiores problemas:

Os comandos abaixo devem ser executados dentro de um repositório local, já inicializado com `git init`.

Adicione um repositório remoto:

```
git remote add origin https://usuario-e-repositorio-do-github-ou-bitbucket
```

[(se tiver problemas com git remote add)](https://help.github.com/pt/github/using-git/adding-a-remote)

Por padrão, o comando git se recusa a mesclar históricos que não compartilham um ancestral comum. O primeiro comando abaixo será usado para ignorar isso:

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Baixa o que tem no repositório remoto, faça mesmo que esteja vazio:

```
git pull origin master
```

Será adicionado ao stagging os arquivos do diretório e sub-diretórios que você está:

```
git add .
```

Identifique o que você vai subir...

```
git commit -m "Mensagem para esse push"
```

Faça o upload:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade basta seguir o passo a passo depois de criar o repositorio no github. Então você usa o:

```
git add remote "link do repositorio"
```

Depois você usa o:

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Comentario"
```

e por fim

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Da um Git Pull antes depois só digitar..

```
git push -u https://github.com/nome do repositorio/nome do projeto master -f
```

Ai sim coloca o `git push https://github.com/repositorio/nomedoprojeto`